# Styling the typeahead.js list (the bootstrap way)

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead.js, twitter-typeahead

I'm trying to create an autocomplete text field using `typeahead.js`. The examples [here](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/) show suggestion lists that are nicely formatted. However, when I use the same code, I only get a bland list of suggestions like so:

[image]

Please see this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BxRv5/6/) for the code.

I'm using `Bootstrap` with it. What do I have to do to get a list that is formatted the `Bootstrap` way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the default output has no styling at all and the `.tt` class has to be used to style the list. I got the following code by inspecting the element I wanted, tweak to suit your needs.

```
.tt-query,
.tt-hint {
    width: 396px;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 30px;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 8px;
    outline: none;
}

.tt-query {
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
}

.tt-hint {
    color: #999
}

.tt-dropdown-menu {
    width: 422px;
    margin-top: 12px;
    padding: 8px 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

.tt-suggestion {
    padding: 3px 20px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 24px;
}

.tt-suggestion.tt-cursor {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #0097cf;

}

.tt-suggestion p {
    margin: 0;
}
```